# maintain the choices after submit in ajax concatenated select

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I made a form with some dynamic/concatenated select in this way.

FORM HTML (index.php)

```
<form id="src_form" action="index.php" method="post">
<p>
<select name="catid_1" id="catid_1" class="fieldmax">
   <?php echo $cs->show_cat_1(''); ?>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<select name="catid_2" id="catid_2" class="fieldmax">
   <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<select name="catid_3" id="catid_3" class="fieldmax">
   <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SRC" id="btn_src">
</p>
</form>
```

AJAX JS

```
$(function() {

// Ajax post Page
var urlpage = 'ajax-php/con-select.php';

// Vars 
var wait = '<option value="">wait</option>';
var all = '<option value="">all</option>';

// Default
$("select#catid_2").prop("disabled", true);
$("select#catid_3").prop("disabled", true);

// CATID_1 Change
$("select#catid_1").change(function(){

// set var
var catid_1 = $("select#catid_1 option:selected").prop("value");

// laod
$("select#catid_2").html(wait);


$.post(urlpage, 
{ 
    catid_1:catid_1 
}, 
function(data){

    switch (data) {

        case all:
            $("select#catid_2").html("");
        return false;

        default:
            $("select#catid_2").prop("disabled", false);
            $("select#catid_2").html(data);
        return false;
        }
    });
});

// CATID_2 Change ... etc

});
```

CON-SELECT.PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['catid_1']))
{
    echo $cs->show_cat_2();
    die;
}

if(isset($_POST['catid_2']));
{
    echo $cs->show_cat_3();
    die;
}
```

CLASS.PHP

```
public function show_cat_1() 
{
$result = $this->db->mysqli->query
("SELECT * FROM cat_1 ORDER BY idcat_1 ASC");

$cat_1 = '<option value="">all</option>';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
$cat_1 .= '<option value="' . $row['idcat_1'] . '"';
$cat_1 .= '>' . $row['idcat_1'] . '</option>';
}
return $cat_1;
}

public function show_cat_2() 
{
$result = $this->db->mysqli->query
("SELECT * FROM cat_2 ORDER BY idcat_2 ASC");

$cat_2 = '<option value="">all</option>';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
$cat_1 .= '<option value="' . $row['idcat_2'] . '"';
$cat_1 .= '>' . $row['idcat_2'] . '</option>';
}
return $cat_2;
}

etc..
```

my goal is to keep the choices (select value) in fields after submit the form (reload page) while maintaining their functionality. you can do it? how could I do that? thanks

Comment: simple pass the selecte choice to action and when output the page set selected the option that you stored before.

Comment: I tried, but without success, you may give me an example please? thanks

Comment: did you have try with attr "selected" ?